# How to make multiple instances of a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a collectionView of images so that when an image is clicked a tableview is presented. My tableview displays posts that are queried from my parse server, but when I go back to my collection view and click on a different image, I am taken to a view controller displaying the same data.

I am trying to get each collectionview image's table view to query its own unique set of posts.

How do I create a separate instance of tableview for each collection view image?

The code I have in my collection view's didSelectItemAtIndexPath:

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false

     // navigate to preference view
    let post = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTableView") as! myTableView
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(post, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation of `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, you never use the `indexPath` parameter. It simply means that your code doesn't care about which cell was selected and you will always have the same view controller with the same data presented.

In order to have it to work, in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`method, keep a reference to the `indexPath` selected, or even in the data corresponding To this indexpath (the data you actually use in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`).

Then, in your view controller containing the collectionView, override `prepareForSegue` and use it to pass the data to the ViewController with the tableview before it is pushed. 
More info from [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a variable in your 'myTableView' and give it a value before 'pushViewController'. Something like that:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
//GET CLICKED
var YOUROBJECT = YOURARRAYOFIMAGES.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
 // navigate to preference view
let postView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTableView") as! myTableView
postView.post = YOUROBJECT.post
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(postView, animated: true)
```